# onclick listener in android for buttons

Tags: android, button, view, onclick

In my android application I'm changing button image for 1 sec. There is group of buttons. In that 1sec image of any one button is get changed. If in that 1sec I click on that particular button I want to perform some operation.using onclick listener i tried.but its not working.How can I do this?please help me
below is the code-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.next);

  // **here i want to call method for onclick of button.**
 //      buttonclick();
  myTimer = new Timer();

  myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {  

    @Override
    public void run() {
      if(time==-1){

        onStop();
      }
      else
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

          Random rand=new Random();               
          time=time-1;
          but1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
          but1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);
          but1.setContentDescription("happy");
          but2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
          but2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);
          but2.setContentDescription("happy");

          int num = rand.nextInt(buttonIds.length);
          int buttonId = buttonIds[num];

          Button bb=(Button) findViewById(buttonId);

          if(bb.getContentDescription().equals(button.getContentDescription()))
          {
            bb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy);
            bb.setContentDescription("happy");
            wrong++;
          }
          else
          {
            bb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whoa);
            count++;

            bb.setContentDescription("whoa");
          }

        }
      });
    }

  },0, 1000);
}

    public void onClick(View v){
 //when i clicked on any button its not even entering here
    System.out.println("in onlcik............");
    int aaa=v.getId();
    System.out.println("click id is------------"+aaa);
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
    if(aaa==buttonIds[i]){
        findViewById(buttonIds[i]).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            Drawable dd=findViewById(buttonIds[i]).getBackground();
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
             System.out.println("yes...");

            }
        });
    }
    }
}

 }
```

i have updated code-i used onclicklistener.but its also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have correctly set `onClick` handlers for your buttons, you can invoke it by simply call `button.performClick()`

Comment: i have 10 buttons.i want to call one function in that i want to get id of button which is clicked.like view.getId(); how can i write this in that function.

Comment: Just define a variable e.g. `lastButtonId` and set it to `button.getId();` when you handle the button `onClick()`

Comment: in buttonclick() function Button last = null;
  int i=last.getId();//here getting exception null pointer
  System.out.println("button is.........."+i);

Comment: i need View in that function.so that i can get button id.how can i get view??